# Уведомление для мессенджера

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Проблема в том что я не могу сделать уведомление (когда приходит сообщение даже на заблокированный экран)
Когда я отправляю сообщение моему собеседнику, у него оно должно появиться, если приложение свернуто или закрыто,в том числе если экран заблокирован.

Для передачи сообщений я пользуюсь Firebase, подобные темы я искал, но толком ничего не нашел
Если использовать NotificationCompat.Builder то уведомления будут приходить тебе, это хорошо когда есть какие-то внутренний таймеры, но для сообщений не очень, как только ты отправил сообщение тебе сразу же пришло уведомление.
Пробовал FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener но не понял к чему токены, и какой в них смысл, и как ими управлять. 
Если кто может помочь, или же подсказать куда копать буду очень признателен. Спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понятно в чём у вас проблема. Работать это должно примерно так: 1. Девайс, на который должно придти сообщение отсылает на сервер свой ID, полученный из `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener` 2. Сервер отправляет пуш на этот ID. 3. Девайс принимает пуш в `onMessageReceived` в наследнике `FirebaseMessagingService` 3. Сервер должен слать только `data` поле без `notification` в теле пуша, чтобы не надо было по разному на андроиде обрабатывать приход пуша.

Comment: 4. Андроид также должен обновлять свой ID на сервере когда он поменяется (новый ID будет в `onNewToken` указанного выше сервиса) 5. Сервер должен поддерживать хранение нескольких ID для одного юзера, т.к. у него могут быть разные девайсы одновременно на один акк.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за последовательность действий! Думаю смогу разобраться

Comment: @ЮрийСПб скажите, а можно пример, хотя бы в пару строк, как мне представить `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance()` и куда его дальше передавать? Просто я уже все видео на ютубе глянул и нашел только то что отправляют они сообщения с Firebase, но к примеру когда запускаешь на двух эмуляторах и тестируешь, то ни там ни там это не срабатывает, 3 пункт сделал, 1 плохо понимаю, 4 сделал, 5 не понимаю 2. пункт, можно пожалуйста тоже пример, как он должен отправлять? С помощью `FirebaseMessaging`?

Comment: Сложно дать пример кода, не зная вашего стэка технологий как на клиентской, так и на серверной стороне. Также неизвестно вы ли отвечаете за сервер и как можете влиять на код на нём. Засим могу лишь общие соображения высказать. `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener` выдаст вам `Result`, в котором будет токен. Его надо отправить на сервер. Предполагая, что всё сделано как надо - вам надо Post запрос отправить с этим токеном и `accessToken`-ом авторизации вашего юзера в системе авторизации сервера, чтобы он связал его с вашим акком на сервере.

Comment: В видео на гуглосервисе вы врядли найдёте что-то действительно полезное. Лучше статьи почитать, хотя я и не встречал статей нужной подробности ни на русском, ни на английском. Скорее всего потому, что ваша задача должна делиться на несколько этапов, состоять из серверной и клиентской части и делаться параллельно там и там разными людьми по заранее известному ТЗ. В итоге в сети можно найти решение нужной вам задачи только по кускам, которые надо вместе склеить.

Comment: По пунктам. 1 - см. выше. 2. - сервер, в зависимости от использования того или иного языка берёт библиотеку специальную или вручную вызывает методы API согласно документации. Для Java + Spring есть либа. Она потребует файла-ключа доступа из консоли Firebase и токена девайса для отправки пуша. 5. Неизвестно что и как у вас на сервер, так что скаже лишь общие соображения. В идеальном мире у вас есть таблица юзеров. Надо к ней добавить таблицу токенов для юзеров, получится связь один ко многим. В этой таблице и храните токены юзеров.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо огромное!